# adding tinymce 4.0 dynamically

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am creating the dynamic tinymce as follows:

1. I have created a function separately

   ```
   function dynamicTinymce() {
       tinyMCE.init({
           mode:"exact",
           elements : ""+tinyMceNextId,
           theme : "modern",
           menubar : false,
           plugins : "code textcolor colorpicker",
           //ThemeOptions
           toolbar : "bold,|,italic,|,underline,|,strikethrough,|,bullist,|,numlist,|,outdent,|,indent,|,blockquote,|,fontselect,|,fontsizeselect,|, forecolor,|,backcolor,|,code,|,mybutton",
       });
   }
   ```
2. Now I have added the function by passing "tinyMceNextId".
      var tinyMceNextId = 1000;
3. For every creation of row I am creating a textarea with that id and incremeted after every row created.

I am abled to create tinymce but it is happening for every alternative.
I mean 1001,1003,1005,1007,1009... I am abled to create tinymce but not for 1002,1004,1006,1008...

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is **tinyMceNextId**?

Comment: I am providing id to textarea which is created dynamically,so tinyMceNextId is id of the textarea

Comment: Here, I doubt the generation of dynamic ID and I guess **tinyMceNextId** is a global variable holding that ID. Try `console.log(tinyMceNextId)` and check if values are coming properly.

Comment: Yeah, tinyMceNextId is a global ID. I am able to get new id everytime when I create a textarea. But tinymce is holding something to create a new tinymce. It is creating only every alternative textarea.